# I must say I am lost on what we are talking about here

Tags: grammar

> I must say I am lost on what we are talking about here.

(source : [Duty-free Entry Or Temporary Suspensions of Duty](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=PTLSAAAAMAAJ&q=%22am%20lost%20on%20what%22&dq=%22am%20lost%20on%20what%22&hl=ko&sa=X&redir_esc=y))

Is **"lost on what"** correct English? Should it be written as **"lost about what"** ?
If it's correct English, what does it mean?
I guess it means like **"I don't have a grasp on what we are talking about here"**

Comment: [**Lost on**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lost%20on): *not appreciated or understood by (someone)*.  This seems a colloquial variation on the phrasal verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"lost on what" Good question, it is commonly used where I come from.

However it is correct On is a preposition meaning relating to and Lost on is an idiom meaning not understood.

> I must say I am lost on what we are talking about here

I must say I am lost **in relation to** what we are talking about here

> **on** preposition (RELATING) [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on)
>
> a book on pregnancy

Whilst the phrase Lost on is an idiom meaning: not appreciated or understood by (someone) [MERRIAM-WEBSTER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lost%20on)

> The jokes were lost on me.
>
> Quest for meaning is **lost on** the little’un  [The Guardian UK](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2017/feb/02/quest-for-meaning-is-lost-on-the-littleun)

If we use the idiom here.

> I must say I am lost on what we are talking about here

I must say I am **not understanding** what we are talking about here.

So however you choose to interpret the sentence the meaning is **"They do not understand the conversation"**

Comment: I agree that "lost on" is idiomatic, but I would like to see some kind of supporting evidence to bolster your answer other than "I think it's fine".   Something like a dictionary reference would be sufficient, and even better if you can quote other uses from things like newspaper articles.

Comment: @Andre Noted and done, thanks